# Is this application of strong Markov Property correct?

Tags: probability, markov-process

Let $X_n$ be a DTMC, with transition matrix P and state-space I. Let $Y_m=X_{T_m}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define $T_0=\inf\{n\geq0:X_n\in J\subset I\}$ and $T_{m+1}=\inf\{n> T_{m}:X_n\in J\subset I\}$. These are stopping times, so we can use the strong markov property when conditioning on them.

The author of the book writes the following: $$P(Y_{m+1}=i_{m+1}|Y_0=i_0, ..., Y_m=i_m)=P(X_{T_{m+1}}=i_{m+1}|X_{T_{0}}=i_0,..., X_{T_{m}}=i_m)=P_{i_m}(X_{T_{1}}=i_{m+1})=h^{i_{m+1}}_{i_m}$$ 
where $h^{i_{m+1}}_{i_m}=P(\inf\{n\geq0:X_n=i_{m+1}\}<\infty|X_0=i_m)$

I don't understand the two last equalities...

I would think that $P(X_{T_{m+1}}=i_{m+1}|X_{T_{m}}=i_m)=P(X_{T_{m+1}-T_m}=i_{m+1}|X_{0}=i_m)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: I've posted also at [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558015/using-strong-markov-property), but it has received almost no attention.

Comment: Would you reveal which book this is from?

Comment: @DanielGerigk 'Markov Chains' by J.R. Norris, from Cambridge University Press. Honestly, I was expecting a bit more from this book. The author goes in roundabout ways for some concepts that could be explained in a much more direct way. I've found a few class notes that are much better than this book...

Comment: I sincerely hope the author does not pretend that $$P_{i}(X_{T_{1}}=j)=P(\inf\{n\geq0:X_n=j\}<\infty|X_0=i)$$ since this identity is squarely wrong.

Comment: A cursory consultation of Norris' book indicates that you misapplied a notation introduced in the proof of Theorem 1.3.2 to the setting of Exercise 1.4.4 although Exercise 1.4.4 carefully *defines* $(h_j^i)$ as the minimal non-negative solution of a specific affine system quite unrelated to the probabilities $P(\inf\{n\geq0:X_n=j\}<\infty|X_0=i)$.

Comment: @Did Nice to hear from you ;) and thanks for your interest in this question.

Regarding your comments, if we look at pages 12-13 of said book, we can see that $h^j_i$ is the notation used for the hitting probabilities defined as $P(\inf\{n \geq 0:X_n=j\}|X_0=i)$, which is the minimal non-negative solution of that affine system.

Comment: Once again: just compare systems (1.3) and (1.6).

Comment: @Did aren't both systems (1.3) and (1.6) equivalent? 
Could you help me understand why they are not. 
Thanks for your goodwill. ;)

Comment: ?? Certainly not, (1.6) has $p_{ij}+\ldots$ in the RHS.

Comment: But 1.6 seems to be 1.3 where both equations are written in just one.

Comment: No they are not equivalent. Sorry, just read both pages and compare them.